# Multidimensional char array in C in function

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

How to use function in C with array of strings?
My code:

```
void test(char **a){
    printf("%s", a[0]);
}
int main(){
    char b[10][10];
    strcpy(b[0],"abc");
    strcpy(b[1],"dfgd");
    test(b);
    return 0;
}
```

How to make this example of code work?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know the "real" dimensions of the pointed array in function `test`. I'm quite surprised that it didn't issue a warning on the line `test(b)`. Change `char **a` to `char a[][10]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
void test(char a[10][10]){
    printf("%s", a[0]);
}
```

or

```
void test(char a[][10]){
    printf("%s", a[0]);
}
```

or

```
void test(char (*a)[10]){
    printf("%s", a[0]);
}

int main(){
    char b[10][10];
    strcpy(b[0],"abc");
    strcpy(b[1],"dfgd");
    test(b);
    return 0;
}
```

All three declarations are perfectly equivalent. Although last one is better.

This [answer](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html) explains it better

Comment: I thought it was very bad :( Because as soon as i asked the question the negative votes were flying like wind :(

Comment: You may reopen it (sorry one of the downvotes were mine, and I'm willing to retract them of course if you reopen/undelete the question).

Comment: The link is good, but I think you should at least say that all three declarations are perfectly equivalent. I would also add a hint to prefer the last one for clarity.